# React setState is not updating Always with componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to set a bunch of states but sometimes setState works and sometimes not, and tried with componetWillMount also and no success.
callBack function with setState is triggering alert with null

This is my code

```
componentDidMount(){
var self = this
var uiData = {ui_id:"custReg"}
api('ip/defaultValue/load_DefaultValue', uiData)
.then(function async (response) {
  if(response){
    if(response.data.status){
      var defaultData = response.data.data
      self.setState({ 
        defaultDatas: response.data.data ,
        branches: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Branch"}),
        customerCategories: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Customer 
        Category"}),
        customerTypes: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Customer Type"}),
        titles: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Name Title"}),
        relationTypes: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Relation Type"}),
        maritalStatuses: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Marital 
        Status"}),
        educations: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Education"}),
        occupations: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Occupation"}),
        religions: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Religion"}),
        castes: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Caste"}),
        bloodGroups: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Blood Group"}),
        incomeRanges: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Income Range"}),
        grades: defaultData.filter(data =>{return data.TypeID === "Grading"}),
        allDataSet:true
      }, () => {
        if(self.state.branches){
          self.forceUpdate()
          alert(JSON.stringify(self.state.branches))
        }
      }); 
    }else{
      alert("Unable to load default data.")
    }
  }else{
    alert("Unable to connect.")
  }
})
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

See,
`React doesn't guarantee that the state updates are done immediately`. that's the reason, not to call `console.log(this.state)` just after the setting the state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am alerting inside the callback function, so it should update, right?

Comment: No! It's not guarantee even it is in callback